# Find domains of convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I tried to solve this question but the final solution which I obtain is not the as same as in the text book

**Find domains of convergence of the series**
$$\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{1.3.5...(2n-1)}{n!}(\frac{1-z}{z})^n$$

**The book answer is $|z-\frac{4}{5}|\lt \frac{2}{3}$**

**But my answer is $$|\frac{1-z}{z}|\lt \frac{1}{2}$$**

Is this true ??

How can I obtain the solution as in  the book .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct :

$$\left|\frac{1-z}z\right|<\frac12\iff|2-2z|<|z|$$

Now put $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\implies 2-2z=(2-2x)-2yi\;$ , so::

$$|2-2z|^2<|z|^2\iff(2-2x)^2+4y^2<x^2+y^2\iff$$

$$4-8x+4x^2+4y^2<x^2+y^2\iff3x^2-8x+3y^2+4<0\iff$$

$$3\left(x-\frac43\right)^2-\frac{16}3+3y^2+4<0\iff 3\left(x-\frac43\right)^2+3y^2<\frac43\iff$$

$$\left(x-\frac43\right)^2+y^2<\left(\frac23\right)^2\iff\left|z-\frac43\right|<\frac23$$

Comment: simple error in $x^2-y^2$

Comment: Thanks @HamadaAl. Still, you have a $\;\frac45\;$ where I have a $\;\frac43\;$ ...

Comment: thanks for you ,Now I think this error from the book

Answer (score 1):

@DonAntonio Your solution is correct :

$$\left|\frac{1-z}z\right|<\frac12\iff|2-2z|<|z|$$

Now put $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\implies 2-2z=(2-2x)-2yi\;$ , so::

$$|2-2z|^2<|z|^2\iff(2-2x)^2+4y^2<x^2+y^2\iff$$

$$4-8x+4x^2+4y^2<x^2+y^2\iff3x^2-8x+3y^2+4<0\iff$$

$$3\left(x-\frac43\right)^2-\frac{16}3+3y^2+4<0\iff 3\left(x-\frac43\right)^2+3y^2<\frac43\iff$$

$$\left(x-\frac43\right)^2+y^2<\left(\frac23\right)^2\ldots$$

Thus
  $$|z-\frac43|\lt \frac23 $$

Comment: That $\;\frac45\;$ at the end should be $\;\frac43\;$ ...+1